# ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata (GCP VM error log)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I saw some error log in my GCP vm (ubuntu 16.04), what does it means? and without networking at that time.

Sep 27 00:16:11 myhost google-clock-skew: ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata. .
Sep 27 00:16:14 myhost google-accounts: ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata. .
Sep 27 00:16:14 myhost google-networking: ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata. .

Comment: Is your issue resolved?If yes, can you  post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Comment: Hello @ned, if you think that shamma answer helped you, please consider accepting it (✔️). I'd really appreciate it .Have a great day, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your vm has stopped communication with the local metadata server. There are different reasons for this to occur.

It could be if your machine experienced high CPU load,  when the host machine experienced high CPU load it causes the networking to degreade.

You can check the CPU utilization within the VM using `top` command. If your VM is using high CPU than you can either, close the processes using the CPU or upgrade your GCE VM size.

The steps to change the GCE VM size are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance).

Also it will be helpful if you allocate [enough memory to your machine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type#adding_extended_memory_to_an_existing_vm_instance) according to the utilization.

Another possibility for this error to occur is when the GCE guest environment is not setup correctly. GCE linux VM has daemons running which are responsible for setting the guest environment.

You need to make sure those scripts are running on your VM.
You can use `ps -aux | grep google_` command to confirm. This [document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages#daemons) has more information about setting Linux guest environment.

Another easy fix would be to restart your VM which will start the GCE scripts during the boot process.